# How to combine RESTful calls and Apache wink?

Tags: apache, rest, system-design

I have a question about the REST and Apache wink. I want to use the Apache Wink to handle the transition between front end and back end. However, I don't have any ideas on how to start and learn it. Can anyone help me? thank you.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://incubator.apache.org/wink/documentation.html  If the docs can't get you started then maybe it is not the right tool for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it has the tutorial and the example

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-richjava/index.html

http://incubator.apache.org/wink/